# jQuery load div content right syntax

Tags: jquery, variables, syntax, load

What is the right syntax for the following?

`postid` is the slug I need to add to the url;
I need the content only of the `article` div from the remote page;
I'm also passing the `postid` to the remote page

```
.load("http://something/crew/?=" + postid .article ,{id:postid});
```

Thanks.

Based on the answer below the right syntax is:

```
.load("http://something/crew/?=" + postid + " .article" ,{id:postid});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.load("http://something/crew/?id=" + postid  + " .article");
```

Note that there is a space before `.article`.

From http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

> If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.